# how can i get image pixels and save it in int array?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get image pixels and save it in an array of int but when i check the array values sometimes fill it with 0's and other times with strange values (all the array have same value).

```
iv = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.uploadImage);
iv.buildDrawingCache();
bmap = iv.getDrawingCache();
bmap.getPixels(pix, 0, width, 0, 0, width, hieght);

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for(int i :pix) {
    builder.append("   " + i + "    ");
}
Toast.makeText(this, builder, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int[] pixels = new int[yourBitmap.getHeight() * yourBitmap.getWidth()];
yourBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, yourBitmap.getWidth(), yourBitmap.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few possible problems here:

- `setDrawingCacheEnabled()` isn't called

  For this, you simply need to call [`setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled%28boolean%29) before using the cache. Make sure you set it back to false when you're done, or your ImageView won't render(at least on non-hardware accelerated devices)
- `width` and `height` may not be right

  I don't kow where you're getting your values for these, but you should use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` for it. If you want to set it to a different value, that's fine, but then you need to create a scaled bitmap from the original one. Otherwise, there's no guarantee that the bitmap you get is the same size you think it is.
- `pix` may be the wrong size

  Hand in hand with the last point. Once you have accurate values for height and width, you need to make sure the array is the right size. `pix = new int[height * width]` is fine for this.

Answer (score -1):

The third parameter should not be width.
Third parameter is called stride:  The number of entries in pixels[] to skip between rows (must be >= bitmap's width).

Try 
`bmap.getPixels(pix, 0, width-1, 0, 0, width, hieght);`

Comment: In most cases, this is bad advice. For typical bitmaps, refer the docs: `For normal packed results, just pass width for the stride value.`  Also, you say it must be `>= bitmap's width`, which is true, but your code says `width-1`, which is invalid.